# Negation of a statement

Tags: logic

So I am trying to prove a proposition. It goes like this

Let there be $\emptyset\neq X\subset\mathbb{R}$
  which is bounded from above. The next two statements are equivalent about $s\in\mathbb{R}
 $

1) i)$ x\leq s$ $\forall x\in X$

ii) If $x\leq u$
$  \forall x\in X$
  then $s\leq u$

2) i)$x\leq s$
  $\forall x\in X$

ii*)$\forall\epsilon>0$
$  \exists x\in X$
  s.t $s-\epsilon<x\leq s$

So I am trying to prove $2\Rightarrow1$, in other words to prove $ii* \Rightarrow ii$. I wanted to prove it by contradiction but I couldn't figure out how to negate ii. As I know it, if we have two statements A and B with $A \Rightarrow B$ then the negation would be $\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$.Here, for example A=If $u \leq x$ $\forall x \in X$ and B is $s \leq u$. But when I applied it, it really didn't make any sense. Maybe I have the wrong idea of negation. Can someone explain me where I am wrong with the negation? Thank you.

Comment: NO; the *negation* of A⇒B is **not** ¬B⇒¬A; the two are *equivalent*, i.e. they have "the same meaning".

Comment: If ii) is : $∀x∈X (x≤u \rightarrow s≤u)$ its negation will be : $\exists x \in X(x≤u \land s > u)$ i.e. "there is an x such that $x \le u < s$".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  I think I got confused with contrapositive and negation. Now I understand , Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *negation* of $A \rightarrow B$ is :

> $\lnot (A \rightarrow B)$ --- **(*)**.

To "move inside" the negation sign, we have to use the equivalence between $p \rightarrow q$ and $\lnot p \lor q$ and De Morgan : $\lnot(p \lor q)$ is equivalent to $\lnot p \land \lnot q$.

Thus **(*)** is :

> > $\lnot (\lnot A \lor B)$ i.e. $A \land \lnot B$.

Answer (score 2):

If ii) is **not** true then some $u$ must exist with $x\leq u$ for each
$x\in X$ and secondly $u<s$.

Taking $\varepsilon=s-u>0$ we then
find that ii*) cannot be true.

Proved is now that ii*) implies ii).